# Trying to get property of non-object when looping mysqli results

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to list the data of 2 related tables, I tried the query separately and it brings the correct data but when I put the query in PHP I get an error

> Trying to get property of non-object in D:\ph\control.php on line 56

```
<?php  
include "modelo/conexion.php";
$sql=$conexion->query(" SELECT p.id_poke,p.nombre,t.tipo,g.genero 
                        FROM poke AS p INNER JOIN tipo AS t ON p.id_tipo=t.id_tipo 
                        INNER JOIN genero AS g ON p.id_genero=g.id_genero ");

while($datos=$sql->fetch_assoc()){?>



<tr>
    
    <td><?=$datos->p.id_poke ?></td>
    <td><?= $datos->p.nombre ?></td>
    <td><?= $datos->t.tipo ?></td>
    <td><?= $datos->g.genero ?></td>
    <td>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-small btn-danger"><i class="fa-regular fa-pen-to-square"></i></a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-small btn-danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></a>   
    </td>
</tr>
<?php  
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your error should be pretty clear; `$datos` is not an object, so you can't use Object Access `$datos-> ...`. Also, `$datos->p.id_poke` is invalid anyway, that would have to be `$datos->{'p.id_poke'}`. Did you maybe mean `$datos['id_poke']`? Also, please do some debugging on your end _before_ asking a question. `dump($datos)` will show you what it is/contains, and you should be able to use that to fix your issue.

Comment: Is this a typo? Did you mean to use `fetch_object` instead of `fetch_assoc`?

Answer (score 1):

I think, that You fetched data as associative array, so it's not object

I'm not sure at 100% because there no enough code.

Insted of getting data from object, try array like this:

```
<td><?=$datos['id_poke'] ?></td>
<td><?= $datos['nombre'] ?></td>
<td><?= $datos['tipo'] ?></td>
<td><?= $datos['genero'] ?></td>
```

To be sure just run

```
var_dump($datos);
```

Comment: You are correct, so I do not understand why you are unsure about your answer. Clearly they are fetching an array from the `mysqli_result` object because of `fetch_assoc`. You don't need to see more code. I would remove this from your answer and just focus on explaining how to do it right.

Comment: I'm not sure, because we don't know what methods has $conexion variable included in modelo/conexion.php. I can think it is PDO class instance or mysqli, but reading this code it's not sure

Comment: It's not PDO. It's mysqli. It's a PHP extension that allows access to MySQL databases only. It was created to enable people quick migration to PHP 5. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: ok, it could be mysqli, forgot about this function because usually i'm using pdo or doctrine ;)